# Average of Same Cell Across Multiple Sheets

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, average

I tried

```
=AVERAGE(Jeff!C2,Blaze!C2,Hunter!C2,Alexia!C2)

=AVERAGE(Jeff:Alexia!C2)
```

Those names are sheet names and the formula is in cell C2 in the master sheet called 'FINAL SCORE'.

Error is

> This value doesn't match the data validation restrictions defined for
> this cell.

I need a formula or macro that to take the value in the same cell 'C2' in each sheet, and give me the average. C2 can only have numbers 0 through 10 (I locked this on each sheet).

This would then be replicated for each cell contiguously so same formula for D2, E2, F2 etc. (to aggregate scoring in a final column which I already have a working formula for.

Screenshot of Final Score sheet layout - every sheet looks identical except the other sheets have numbers ranging from 0-10 in C2
[image]

I am working on a project to rank anime that a group of friends watch to provide ranking/recommendations to each other.

Comment: Short of having something dynamic, it worked for me (first formula your provided) and can average values across multiple sheets in a single formula.  Have you tried using `INDIRECT` to see if that works for you?

Comment: Just remove your validation on the cell containing the formula. There-s nothing wrong with the formula itself.

Answer (score 2):

### Range.Consolidate Method

- [`Range.Consolidate method`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.consolidate)
- [`XlConsolidationFunction enumeration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlconsolidationfunction)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ConsolAverage()
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FINAL SCORE").Range("C2:L2")
        Dim cell As Range
        For Each cell In .Cells
            cell.Consolidate Array( _
                "Jeff!RC", "Blaze!RC", "Hunter!RC", "Alexia!RC"), xlAverage
        Next cell
    End With
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

- Maybe try the following UDF by using `=ConAVG()` in each cell:

```vb
Function ConAVG() As Double
    Application.Volatile
    
    Const wsNamesList As String = "Jeff,Blaze,Hunter,Alexia"

    Dim wsNames() As String: wsNames = Split(wsNamesList, ",")
    Dim CellAddress As String: CellAddress = Application.Caller.Address
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim cValue As Variant
    Dim Total As Double
    Dim tCount As Long
    
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(wsNames)
        cValue = ws.Range(CellAddress)
        If IsNumeric(cValue) Then
            If Len(cValue) > 0 Then ' exclude blanks
                Total = Total + cValue
                tCount = tCount + 1
            End If
        End If
    Next ws
    If tCount = 0 Then Exit Function
    
    ConAVG = Round(Total / tCount, 2)

End Function
```